# Order of operations - is there any standard?

Tags: math-history

Is there any standard regarding order of mathematical operations? I only found ISO 31-11 that deals with mathematical symbols, but not with the order of operations.

If there's not, I'd be interested in some paper regarding its history and why do we use it the way we do - although it's not standardized.

Comment: The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) is a good start, not to imply you have not already read this.